# Connection Refused While Accessing API

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have a nginx server where I have an api deployed at localhost:5000

On the same server I have a Vuejs app which is deployed at localhost:3000 and then through nginx reverse proxy served from www.mysite.com.

the frontend uses axios to make calls to the api. But everytime it happens, I get a connection refused error to localhost:5000.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it.

Note: If I serve localhost:5000 api also via a domain like api.mysite.com using nginx reverse proxy and call api from this domain then it works fine. But I don't want to do that and instead want to use localhost:5000 to call the api.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port is listed by using the following command if you use Linux

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :5000
```

If there is process running, then fine. Try changing the localhost to 127.0.0.1:5000